# Help with T-SQL Joins

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, join

So I have a table that links IP's to votes/flags of messages called `tblIPMessageLink`

It contains the IP that voted or flagged, and a bit column for 'voted' and 'flagged'.

The `getMessages` proc is below

```
SELECT
  m.message,
  m.votes,
  m.messageId,
  ml.voted,
  ml.flagged,
  NULL as rows
FROM
  tblMessages m
left join tblIPMessageLink ml on m.messageid = ml.messageid
WHERE
  m.timestamp >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @date), 0)
  and
  m.timestamp < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @date), 1)
  and
  datediff(hour,m.timestamp, getdate()) <= 2
ORDER BY datediff(hour,m.timestamp, getdate()) DESC
```

Even if I exec this proc passing in an IP that does NOT exist in the link table, it still comes up as having voted for the message. It shouldn't, because I voted from a different IP.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my join line should look like this:

```
left join tblIPMessageLink ml on m.messageid = ml.messageid and ml.ip = @ip
```

Comment: You could also put the IP condition in the where clause.  Seems like it would make more sense there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `left join` means that the query is going to list all rows in the table on the "left" (the message table) and display the corresponding row or null from the other table (the link table).  if you're taking the existence of a result row as the existence of a vote, that's your problem.  You're going to get back values for all the `m` rows and NULL for `ml.voted` and `ml.flagged`.

The solution is to switch the tables' position in the sproc.

Comment: It's returning the correct rows, but the incorrect values for the voted/flagged rows. It's returning a 'true' bit in those cases, when it should be returning NULL.

Comment: @slandau - Is there more to the sproc that you can post?  I.e. a where clause, or what @lastId is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> It's returning a 'true' bit in those
>   cases, when it should be returning
>   NULL.

and on the query you posted I think that the problem is in the data. There is no way a query for a particular field can return anything but this field or NULL. If you see true, then true is what is stored in this field for corresponding MessageId Could you please:

- Choose a single MessageId that exhibits the problem
- Run you query filtering on this MessageId and post here the resulting recordset
- Dump all the rows from tblMessages with chosen MessageId and post here
- Dump all the rows from tblIPMessageLink with chosen MessageId and post here

It would also help if you provide:

- Definition of tblMessages (along with keys, constraints, etc)
- Definition of tblIPMessageLink (along with keys, constraints, etc)

Comment: It should be returning the value for the corresponding messageId AND ip address though.

Comment: The IP address is not a part of the SQL query that you have posted. Since you are not using it anywhere in the query, it's just a field on one of the tables. It will be returned with the rest of them if you query for it.

Comment: That was my question though :)